# Compile PyAudio without Jack, without PulseAudio, etc

Tags: linux, alsa, portaudio, pyaudio

I want to compile `PyAudio` with as few layers as possible.
I only want to use `PortAudio` (needed for `PyAudio`) which uses ALSA, **but not Jack, not PulseAudio, not anything else**.

I would like to have `PyAudio <--> PortAudio <--> ALSA` and nothing more.

When doing:

```
git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git
cd pyaudio
sudo python setup.py install
```

it will link the library with Jack, etc. that I don't want.

**How to compile PyAudio with nothing else than PortAudio and ALSA?**

*Reason: debug some problems, that might be related to the other layers.*

Answer (score 1):

When you install PyAudio as you showed it, it will use the PortAudio library which is already installed on your system (e.g. via `apt-get`).

If you want PortAudio without JACK, you'll have to get the sources from http://www.portaudio.com/ and compile it yourself using:

```
./configure --without-jack
```

I think PulseAudio isn't directly supported anyway.
If you don't want PulseAudio to interfere, it may be easiest to just uninstall it.